# Is there a defined draw order for OpenGL instanced drawing?

Tags: opengl, geometry-instancing

I want to draw a large number of overlapping, opaque objects, using OpenGL instancing. To keep the fill rate down, I want to sort from near the camera to far from it. If I order the values in the buffers in the order that I want the drawing to happen, does the standard dictate that OpenGL must draw them in that order? It would be a big waste of compute to sort the buffers if they were going to be drawn in parallel, or in an unspecified order.